# Reset a Table with Rich in Python, or delete a row?

Tags: python, rich

*How could I erase a row table in rich?
(Erase the rows or reset all the table)*

**ex. How could I reset tableTest or erase a row?**

```
from rich.console import Console
from rich.table import Table

tableTest = Table(title="Star Wars Movies")

tableTest.add_column("Released", justify="right", style="cyan", no_wrap=True)
tableTest.add_column("Title", style="magenta")
tableTest.add_column("Box Office", justify="right", style="green")

tableTest.add_row("Dec 20, 2019", "Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker", "$952,110,690")
tableTest.add_row("May 25, 2018", "Solo: A Star Wars Story", "$393,151,347")
tableTest.add_row("Dec 15, 2017", "Star Wars Ep. V111: The Last Jedi", "$1,332,539,889")
tableTest.add_row("Dec 16, 2016", "Rogue One: A Star Wars Story", "$1,332,439,889")

console = Console()
console.print(tableTest)
```

Comment: How do you know that there are such methods as `add_column` or `add_row`? By looking in the documentation, right? Did you try looking through the documentation again, to see if there is anything that looks like it might do what you now want?

Comment: Yes i did. This question it's my desperate act.
https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/table.html
https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, rich does not provide any APIs to Delete/Remove the rows. See this [Support for deleting/removing rows/columns from table](https://github.com/Textualize/rich/issues/1331) to understand why no such APIs are added to the `Table` class.

Answer (score 1):

Just reinitialize the table.

```
def resetTable():
    global tableTest

    tableTest = Table(title="Star Wars Movies")

    tableTest.add_column("Released", justify="right", style="cyan", no_wrap=True)
    tableTest.add_column("Title", style="magenta")
    tableTest.add_column("Box Office", justify="right", style="green")
```

And call `resetTable()` whenever you want to reset your table